# How do I access the SQLite DB my app uses on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Is there any way of getting the SQLite DB off my iPhone so I can view the data in it?

I've managed to get the DB on my iPhone into an odd state, and rather than keep trying to replicate in simulator, I'd like to investigate the state of the DB from my dev install.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check out Andy Finnell's [Blog post](http://www.losingfight.com/blog/2008/08/14/how-to-get-application-data-from-the-iphone/)

In a nutshell you can use either XCode to get your application's data or use the iTunes iphone backup functionality.